# find command error in shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, find

I have a file "log_data.txt" which contains various log files and the mtime next to the names with a space. Contents of the file are as shown below,

```
Log1 2
Log2 6
Log3 5
Log4 7
Log5 3
```

The intent here is my script shown below has to assign itself the log filename and delete the files as per the mtime next to it.

```
IFS=''
while read line
do
find /opt/tmp/log/ -name `$line | awk '{print $1}'`*.log -mtime `$line | awk '{print $2}'` -exec rm -rf {} \;
echo ---------
done < log_data.txt
```

If I assign an integer next to mtime in the script, it works fine, but, it throws the below error, if I put **"`$line | awk '{print $2}'`"** in the find command.

```
---------
./log_clear_script.sh: line 4: Log1      2: not found
./log_clear_script.sh: line 4: Log1      2: not found
find: invalid argument `-exec' to `-mtime'
---------
./log_clear_script.sh: line 4: Log2     6: not found
./log_clear_script.sh: line 4: Log2     6: not found
find: invalid argument `-exec' to `-mtime'
---------
./log_clear_script.sh: line 4: Log3       5: not found
./log_clear_script.sh: line 4: Log3       5: not found
find: invalid argument `-exec' to `-mtime'
---------
./log_clear_script.sh: line 4: Log4  7: not found
./log_clear_script.sh: line 4: Log4  7: not found
find: invalid argument `-exec' to `-mtime'
---------
./log_clear_script.sh: line 4: Log5        3: not found
./log_clear_script.sh: line 4: Log5        3: not found
find: invalid argument `-exec' to `-mtime'
```

Please help me resolve it. All responses are much appreciated. - Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

the variable
    `$line`
is not a command. it's just a string.

try to substitute

```
`$line | awk '{print $1}'`
```

with

```
`echo -n $line | awk '{print $1}'`
```

and

```
`$line | awk '{print $2}'`
```

with

```
`echo -n $line | awk '{print $2}'`
```

Answer (score 1):

change

```
 `$line | awk '{print $2}'`
```

To

```
`echo $line | awk '{print $2}'`
```